# How does Luigi's require work?

Tags: python-2.7, scheduled-tasks, spotify, luigi

I am using Luigi tool of Spotify to handle dependencies between several jobs.

```
def require(self):
        yield task1()`
        info = retrieve_info()
        yield task2(info=info)
```

In my example, I'd like to require from `task1`, then retrieve some information that depends on the execution of `task1` in order to pass it as an argument of `task2`. However, my function `retrieve_info` won't work because `task1` has not runned yet.

My question is, since I am using `yield`, `task1` should not process before the call of `retrieve_info` is made? Is Luigi iterating over the required function and then launching the processing of the different task?

If this last assumption is right, how can I use execution of a required task as an input of a second required class?

Comment: Discussed over here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/luigi-user/3oILukg5o4I